# Replace query with hyphen by a substraction

Tags: java

I'm searching on the web for several times but did not found anything which could help me (in java).

In fact I need to search in a sql table some rows from some reference which contains an hyphen. The issue made is that the sql replace my reference by the result of a substraction. The type of the columns are string.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT * FROM WAREHOUSE WHERE REF LIKE('96-18')" ;
Statement statement = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("S_FAMILY"));
}
```

In this code, it replaces my reference by 78 and does not naturaly return the good result.

I've searched for an escape char but did not found.

Comment: The expression after the `LIKE` operator doesn't need parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending the `String` as parameter on the query. Doing this requires to change the `Statement` into `PreparedStatement`:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM WAREHOUSE WHERE REF LIKE(?)" ;
PreparedStatement pstatement = con.prepareStatement(query,
            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
pstatement.setString(1, "96-18");
ResultSet rs = pstatement.executeQuery();
```

Note: you should send `"96-18"` as value of a `String` variable, do not hard code it.

Comment: No it does not work, the method executeQuery() does not accept any argument for a PreparedStatement or a CallableStatement.
Even if i try it without an argument, it does not work correctly, i've already worked in this way and i never had any problem.

I work with SqlServer Driver, in an other software i've worked with H2 and i don't think that it made the same issue.

Comment: no problem, and many thanks for your help but the problem is'nt solved yet

Comment: @pidel maybe it's just me, but I think the `String` parameter should be `%96-18%`.

Comment: now it's solved, in fact if we write %96-18% it will take every ref with this "part" of ref and it's not really usefull for me in my soft. Just writing string is enough.

Comment: @pidel how was it solved? Sorry to ask, I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: In fact i was searching a ref which was not good imported in my database. It's for this reason that when i was testing , it did not return the good result. Now, when i give a good ref in the pstatement.setString() it work fine.
thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM WAREHOUSE WHERE REF LIKE('96\-18') ESCAPE '\'
```

Hope it helps